# Showing a supspace to be invariant under normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

prove that if $T\in B(H)$ is normal and $F\subseteq H$ is a subspace of $H$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T,$ then $F^{\perp}$ is invariant for $T.$

where $H$ mean Hilbert space.

how to show.i am trying it by let $$F^{\perp}\  \text{is invariant under T iff} \ F^{\perp\perp} \text{is invarient under } T^{*}$$. which is $$F \  \text{is invariant under } \ T^*$$

now since $T$ is nomal ,hence set of eigenvectors of $T$ and $T^*$ is same.
from this how can show $F$ is invariant under $T^*$., as i donot know about general element of $F$

or any other easy way out there  ??

Comment: you have it, F is an eigenspace of T* and eigenspaces are stable

Comment: @marmouset why $F$ is eigenspace of $T^*$

Comment: because they commute ! any eigenvector of T is eigen vector of T*; straight from the commutation property

Comment: @marmouset eigenspace with respect to which eigenvalue??

Comment: my bad it's a bit more tricky

Comment: What do you mean that the subspace consists of eigenvectors? For example, $0$ is not an eigenvector. Do you mean that the subspace is spanned by eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue? Do you do mean that the subspace is spanned by eigenvectors with different eigenvalues?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts it is not mention  in the problem. i think it subspace contain all possible eigenvector of opeartor $T$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\omega \in F^\perp$, and an arbitrary $f \in F$. We wish to show that $\omega \perp f$. Since $F$ is the space of all eigenvectors for $T$, there is a scalar $\lambda$ such that $Tf = \lambda f$. Then $T^*f = \overline{\lambda}f$.

We have:

$$\langle T\omega, f\rangle = \langle \omega, T^*f\rangle = \langle \omega, \overline{\lambda}f\rangle = \lambda\langle \omega, f\rangle = 0$$

Since $f$ was arbitrary, we have $T\omega \perp F$. Hence, $T\omega \in F^\perp$ so $F^\perp$ is $T$-invariant.

---

To show $T^*f = \overline{\lambda}f$, first note that $\|Tv\| = \|T^*v\|$ for all $v \in H$. Indeed:

$$0 = \langle (T^*T - TT^*)v, v\rangle = \langle T^*v, T^*v\rangle - \langle Tv, Tv\rangle$$

Now, since $T$ is normal, $T - \lambda I$ is also normal:

\begin{align}(T - \lambda I)^*(T - \lambda I) &= (T^* - \overline{\lambda} I)(T - \lambda I) \\
&= T^*T - \lambda T^* - \overline{\lambda} T + |\lambda|^2 \\
&= TT^* - \lambda T^* - \overline{\lambda} T + |\lambda|^2 \\
&= (T - \lambda I)(T^* - \overline{\lambda}I)\\
&= (T - \lambda I)(T - \lambda I)^*
\end{align}

Finally:

$$0 = \|(T - \lambda I)f\| = \|(T - \lambda I)^*f\| = \|(T^* - \overline{\lambda} I)f\|$$

So $T^*f = \overline{\lambda}f$.